# Taking an outer subtraction between a list of tuples using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

**NOTE:** I am not looking for syntax on how to use `np.subtract.outer`, instead I am trying to solve a very specific issue that I am facing during its application.

I have a list of tuples -

```
a = [(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,2)]
a = np.array(a)
```

I am trying to implement a full vectorized subtraction between each element of this list (tuples). I can do it with iterating using `itertools` as shown below expecting a 5x5x2 as -

```
#My attempt with iteration (producing expected results)

np.array([np.array(i[0])-np.array(i[1]) for i in itertools.product(a, a)]).reshape(5,5,2)
```

```
#RESULT (5x5x2) 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [-1,  0],
        [-1, -1],
        [-2,  0],
        [-2, -2]],

       [[ 1,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0, -1],
        [-1,  0],
        [-1, -2]],

       [[ 1,  1],
        [ 0,  1],
        [ 0,  0],
        [-1,  1],
        [-1, -1]],

       [[ 2,  0],
        [ 1,  0],
        [ 1, -1],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0, -2]],

       [[ 2,  2],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 0,  2],
        [ 0,  0]]])
```

However, when using `np.subtract.outer()`. I end up with an array of shape 5x2x5x2 as below -

```
#My attempt with vectorization (producing unexpected results)

np.subtract.outer(a,a) #5x2x5x2
```

```
array([[[[ 0,  0],  #This matrix is same as ....
         [-1,  0],
         [-1, -1],
         [-2,  0],
         [-2, -2]],

        [[ 0,  0],  #This one...
         [-1,  0],
         [-1, -1],
         [-2,  0],
         [-2, -2]]],


       [[[ 1,  1],   #However, this ...
         [ 0,  1],
         [ 0,  0],
         [-1,  1],
         [-1, -1]],

        [[ 0,  0],  #And this, dont repeat! ..
         [-1,  0],
         [-1, -1],
         [-2,  0],
         [-2, -2]]],


       [[[ 1,  1],   #This ...
         [ 0,  1],
         [ 0,  0],
         [-1,  1],
         [-1, -1]],

        [[ 1,  1],   #And this do..
         [ 0,  1],
         [ 0,  0],
         [-1,  1],
         [-1, -1]]],


       [[[ 2,  2],
         [ 1,  2],
         [ 1,  1],
         [ 0,  2],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0],
         [-1,  0],
         [-1, -1],
         [-2,  0],
         [-2, -2]]],


       [[[ 2,  2],
         [ 1,  2],
         [ 1,  1],
         [ 0,  2],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[ 2,  2],
         [ 1,  2],
         [ 1,  1],
         [ 0,  2],
         [ 0,  0]]]])
```

On inspection, I see that some of the matrices are actually repeating two times, while for others it's not the case (as commented above) in output.

My questions are -

1. Why is this duplication happening?
2. How to use `np.subtract.outer` correctly for this example?
3. (or,) How to transform the matrix to the expected one? (5x**2**x5x2) -> (5x5x2)

Note: this is only a toy example. The original list of tuples is massive and float32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use `outer`.  Just use `broadcasting`:

```
In [5]: a[:,None,:]-a[None,:,:]
Out[5]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [-1,  0],
        [-1, -1],
        [-2,  0],
        [-2, -2]],

       [[ 1,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0, -1],
        [-1,  0],
        [-1, -2]],

       [[ 1,  1],
        [ 0,  1],
        [ 0,  0],
        [-1,  1],
        [-1, -1]],

       [[ 2,  0],
        [ 1,  0],
        [ 1, -1],
        [ 0,  0],
        [ 0, -2]],

       [[ 2,  2],
        [ 1,  2],
        [ 1,  1],
        [ 0,  2],
        [ 0,  0]]])
```

`a` is (5,2), with the `None` extension the 2 terms are (5,1,2) and (1,5,2) which together form a (5,5,2) array.

`outer` can be used via:

```
np.subtract.outer(a,a)[:,np.arange(2),:,np.arange(2)].transpose(1,2,0)
```

which removes the duplicates from (5,2,5,2) and reorders the axes.  But it is 3x slower.

Comment: This is perfect! I was so caught up with the np.subtract.outer, that I totally didn't realize that broadcasting would be a viable option. Also, the second part was quite helpful as well thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for `ufunc.outer` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html), it appears `np.subtract.outer` will compute the outer product twice on the diagonal i=j. To me it doesn't look like there's a way to choose just one or the other. I recommend using the broadcasting approach, which lets you decide which dimensions you want to compute the outer product on. `a[:,None]-a[None,:]` gives you the same result as your `itertools` example.

Comment: I was looking into the same for a while. Trying to find an alternate solution without overcomplicating the problem though. Sadly, even though ufunc do have kwargs in documentation, I dont think any of them work for np.ufunc.outer, atleast for subtract.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm a bit lost on the problem. Why do you need an alternate solution to broadcasting? Why do you want to pass `**kwargs` in `ufunc.outer`?

Comment: issue is that for broadcasting i will have to still multiple by array as a cross product.

Answer (score 1):

numpy.ufunc.outer works as expected. What is happening instead, that you are parsing a matrix to itertools.product and thereby lose a factor of 2 (your pairs) when calculating your loop.

- [numpy.ufunc.outer(A,B)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html):
  flattens your input to 1D-arrays. The output would be of length len(A) x len(B). In your case that is: (5x2) x (5x2) = 100. Which is exactly the result you see.
- [itertools.product(A,B)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):
  will go only into the first depth of you objects and apply the product. As they consist of tuples with length two, your call to `p[0]-p[1]` is a subtraction of two tuples. The product itself hence is missing of 2 for the possible combinations of all elements.

Applying flatten() to your input of intertools.product will give the same result as ufunc.outer

```
a = np.array([(0,0), (1,1)]).flatten()
b = np.array([(2,2), (3,3)]).flatten()
c = np.subtract.outer(a, b).flatten()
d = np.asarray([p[0]-p[1] for p in product(a,b)]).flatten()

all(c==d)
> true
```

EDIT:
To answer you questions more specifically:

1. The duplication occurs as numpy.ufunc.outer flattens each input.
2. if you insist using `outer` you might split your inputs, operate outer twice and merge them back together:

```
a = np.array([(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,2)])
b = np.asarray([p[0]-p[1] for p in product(a,a)])
c = np.subtract.outer(a[:,0], a[:,0])
d = np.subtract.outer(a[:,1], a[:,1])
e = np.vstack((c.flatten(),d.flatten())).T
np.all(b==e)
> true
```

Comment: I think you mistook my question. I am looking for the pairwise difference between individual elements of a tuple. I want to get (0,0) - (1,1) as (-1,-1). But I want this to happen in a vectorized way for the cross product of all tuples of the list. The itertools output is the expected result. I am trying to mold the output of the subtract.outer to be same as that... not the other way around.

Comment: Just to clarify further, I have 2 lists of (5x2) and i want to calculate the individual element difference for each tuple. (1x2) - (1x2) = (1x2). And for 5x5 such combinations -> 5x5x2.

Comment: Meanwhile, the outer, is definately working as intended and giving me a cross between (5x2) and (5x2) so (5x2x5x2), but that is not the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Then the flatten operation within numpy.ufunc.outer is a problem for you. Did you solve your problem? If not and if you insist on using 'outer', then you could split your input array, parse it twice to 'outer' and merge the results into one.

Comment: Not solved yet.. the split idea is interesting. Let me think about it. also, there is no need for outer to be necessary but I do need a completely vectorized implementation.